# Error in reading xlsx file using `read.xlsx` function in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to run this command.

```
df <- read.xlsx(add, sheetName = "train1")
```

Then I got this error

> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  :
> java.lang.NullPointerException

What's wrong with this? Can anyone help me? I'm a newbie in R.

Comment: You acn use non Java based package like `openxlsx` to read xlsx files.

Comment: If you show us what the object `add` contains (i.e. the code that created it), it might give us a hint at what the issue is.

Comment: @stragu 'setwd("D:\\11\\2020-2021\\Diplom\\research\\hranalytic")
add <-"train.xlsx"
df <-read.xlsx(add, sheetName= "train1")'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your existing code, you might have to check that your have the right version of Java installed on your computer. On the [Java download page](https://www.java.com/en/download/), pick the version that is right for your operating system and your machine. (And also check that your R packages are up to date, which you can do in RStudio with "Packages tab > Update".)

Alternatively, as Bappa Das suggested, I recommend using an alternative function that doesn't depend on Java (like the package xlsx does, which is I assume the package you are using). For example, try with the readxl package instead:

```r
setwd("D:\\11\\2020-2021\\Diplom\\research\\hranalytic")
add <- "train.xlsx"
library(readxl)
df <- read_xlsx(add, sheet = "train1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use some variation of?:

```
read.table("document.xlsx")
```